# Get express encoded cookie as header value

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, session-cookies

Please see the communication description

1. Client --- POST /login (no cookie yet) ---> Node Server
2. Node Server ---> ‘set-cookie’ : ‘…’ -> Client (sets cookie and uses it for next requests)

How could I get encoded value of the cookie which is set as a set-cookie header before it is sent to the client on the first request ?

Express 3.x, cookieParser, expression-session and a mongo as a storage are used.

I tried:

1. to access `req.cookies` but is not populated on the first request
   because client doesn't have a cookie yet.
2. `res.getHeader('set-cookie')` returns `undefined` perhaps because it
   is set after express route handler is called by express-session.

At the server side how could I access either a set-cookie header in my handler or the cookie value in the response object even if request.cookie is empty ?

Comment: Are you trying to access the cookie in code executed _Clientside_ or _Serverside_? If it's _clientside_, the first time it sees the cookie is in the _response_. If it's _serverside_, look at the headers you're about to/have submitted to the client as you set it, or look at the received headers in _requests_ from the client which arrive **after** it has been set.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Edited the question, specified the server side is in question. The thing is when I check headers to be sent to the client in the node route handler with `res.getHeader('set-cookie')` it returns `undefined`. That's why I wonder if there is some special trick to do it.

Comment: Could you post the code where you set the cookie, and where you're checking the cookie.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Almost a year later, but the reason you can't access is because express-session and other middlewares use a package called [onHeaders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/on-headers) which *"Execute a listener when a response is about to write headers."*

So you have to use it as well to modify the headers

```
var onHeaders = require('on-headers')
onHeaders(res, function(){
    // knock yourself out
    console.log(res.getHeader('set-cookie'));
});
```

Listeners are triggered in reverse order so for you to get the value this code (the listener) must be as soon as possible in your code.